# Incremental class generation from a set of referencing (include/import) XSD schemas

Tags: c#, xsd, code-generation, xsd.exe, auto-generate

Let us assume, I have 3 XSD schemas:

1. BaseSchema.xsd: contains reusable types e.g., position, colour, address, countrylist
2. SchemaA.xsd: includes the base schema and is specific to domain A
3. SchemaB.xsd: includes the base schema and is specific to domain B

I would like to generate their corresponding C# classes. 
I can run

1. "XSD.exe /c SchemaA.xsd BaseSchema.xsd" + "XSD.exe /c SchemaB.xsd BaseSchema.xsd" resulting **2 C# files that containing the classes from BaseSchema 2x. Not good.**
2. "XSD.exe /c SchemaA.xsd SchemaB.xsd BaseSchema.xsd" which results only one C# class for the types in BaseSchema.xsd. This is very nice, but not always possible. For example, **if I have to use a third party assembly already containing the generated class of BaseSchema and Schema B.**

Is there a way to incrementally generate C# classes? E.g., by including assemblies somehow in the command line to instruct the generator reusing the already generated C# classes instead creating them again?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the time and effort you want to put into this, I would

a) use "XSD.exe /c SchemaA.xsd SchemaB.xsd BaseSchema.xsd", delete the generated BaseSchema classes from the file and link to the third party lib instead.

b) use [Xsd2Code](http://xsd2code.codeplex.com/). It doesn't do what you want out of the box but can be easily modified to your needs.

I don't think xsd.exe provides another suitable solution.

Comment: Mark, thank you for your answer, what you write is correct. I have faced several times with this problem, it is not a unique issue. But I have hard time accepting the fact that there is no easier way.

Comment: If you have a quite few (1-2) references between A - base and b - base, you could replace the references to the BaseSchema XML Any type. Any is mapped to object and you have to handle the dependency in your code.